# Spring error in Cucumber java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

I have a cucumber test that is throwing me an illegal access error when I try to fetch a bean. I haven't been able to figure out why this isn't okay.

```
@Given('^test$')
public void myTest(){
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppInjector.class);
    MyBean bean = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class)
}

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class MyBean from StepDef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppInjector.class)
```

to the top of the class, and then use `@Inject` to pull in the dependency.